# How do password managers autofill email and password inputs on all sites?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my own password autofill extension but I am stuck on how password managers somehow change all inputs on any site equally. Some sites that I try and change the input on directly using elem.value= "password" the input values reset when trying to click the login button. I've also tried using custom events and react props to change the value but those haven't worked either. The value in the input seems to change but won't work when the sign-in button is clicked. For reference, I have been testing on the Netflix sign-in page.

Comment: Password managers have special-case code for the sites that work weirdly. You'll need to reverse-engineer those sites, just like those programmers did.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this you can check out https://github.com/bitwarden which is an open-source password manager. Make sure to be tabbed into the page before running fill functions or it may not work!